# Angular 2 More than one component on same page

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working from the Angular 2 quick start code on app.component.ts file.

The file looks like this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<h1>Title Here</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

This works as expected.

What I want to do is to add another component on this same page ... so I tried this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ComponentTwo} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<h1>Title Here</h1>'
}),

@Component({
    selector: 'appTwo',
    template: `<h1>Another Title Here</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

This doesn't work...Is it that I'm doing something wrong or is this not allowed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't have two root components with the same selector in your page, you also can't have two `@Component()` decorators on the same class.

If your components have different selectors, just run bootstrap for each root component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: '<h1>AppComponent1</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent1 { }

@Component({
    selector: 'appTwo',
    template: '<h1>AppComponent2</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent2 { }


bootstrap(AppComponent1)
bootstrap(AppComponent2)
```

There is an open issue to support overriding the selector to be able to add a root component multiple times
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/915

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/915 ? What could be the possible advantages of overriding selectors?

Comment: That you can add the same root component multiple times, still not to the same selector though.

Comment: I wonder if there's any benefit or reason to have multiple bootstrapped `root` components ... any idea? @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: For me the web page *is* an Angular application and it doesn't make much sense to me, but there seem to be quite a few people that want to add smaller features to a page (a page that is not fully controlled by Angular) packed into an Angular component. I can imagine that there are reusable component, that might be initialized with a different parameter (HTML attribute or different providers) to show different data or format them differently. For example a component that displays a list of images.

Comment: can we share a service between those components?
If I add this -> 
bootstrap(AppComponent1, [SomeService])
bootstrap(AppComponent1, [SomeService])
SomeService is created twice

Comment: Just a rookie question: How does `AppComponent1` (or `AppComponent2`) know which `@Component` to target?

Comment: i have a query, please clarify, How a component knows which export class it should take? what is the relation between first component({selector: 'app'}) and export class AppComponent1 { } ?

Comment: The selector is for Flutter to match components with HTML tags, the export is for the TypeScript compiler that compiles TS to JS.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a component with two component decorators (@Component). You need to create two different classes for this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<h1>Title Here</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent { }

@Component({
    selector: 'appTwo',
    template: `<h1>Another Title Here</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent1 { }
```

Then you can use the approach from the Gunter's answer...

Comment: i have a query, please clarify, How a component knows which export class it should take? what is the relation between first component({selector: 'app'}) and export class AppComponent { } ?

Answer (score -2):

Incase this is helpful to anyone, could do the same thing with iFrames. Made a sample you can see here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xWKGS6

Basically i use iframes to load a widget html

```
<iframe src="widget.html" width="500" height="400" style="border:none; background-color:#ccc">
  </iframe>
```

The widget is a normal angular2 html page

Comment: Using a shared service to communication like with other components won't work as easily though.

Comment: Yeah but the example was more about the same component used throughout, each one independent of the other. so like a widget scenario, say for example a whether app where you display the whether of different cities at different places in a site. Figured that would be the only reason someone would want to load it more than one anyway tbh :)

Comment: Using iframes is never a good idea because of the lack of control