# Angular 2: how to load separate, unrelated components on to a page

Tags: angular

I have two completely unrelated components on a page. I do not want to load them as subcomponents under a parent template. How would I load both of them on a single page?

```
<section>
<h1>Heading</h1>
<the-first-component></the-first-component>
</section>

(lots of html)

<main>
<h1>Another heading</h1>
<the-second-component></the-second-component>
</main>

(lot more html)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `bootstrap` for each component

```
bootstrap(AppComponent1, [ /* providers here */]);
bootstrap(AppComponent2, [ /* providers here */]);
```

if you want to share data you can use a shared service for example

```
@Injectable()
class MySharedService {
}

var shared = new MySharedService();

bootstrap(AppComponent1, [provide(MySharedService, {useValue: shared}]);
bootstrap(AppComponent2, [provide(MySharedService, {useValue: shared}]);
```

This way when a `AppComponentx` or one of their sub-components or another service has a constructor parameter like

```
constructor(private myShared: MySharedService) {}
```

then you have the same global instance available everywhere to be able to easily communicate between the different Angular2 "applications" on your page.
See also [detect change of nested property for component input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267119/detect-change-of-nested-property-for-component-input/36267274)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36263181/angular-2-more-than-one-component-on-same-page/36263211#36263211

Comment: If i call bootstrap on all the components and they are not present on the page, i will get an error. Any way to avoid this? My goal is to have multiple reusable components which can be embedded on the page

Comment: @pfried I guess wrapping `bootstrap(...)` in a `try`/`catch` or using a custom error handler like explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488245/custom-exception-handler-in-angular2 should does what you want.